# charting tf idf for survey comments in ggplot2 - label error

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidytext

I'm just beginning to use R for text mining and have come across a problem.

I have successfully charted tf_idf for single words in my dataset which includes 3 different columns (positive, negative, and bank) - the column name is 'Box'.

I am trying to do the same for bigrams and trigrams and using the same code:

```
Trigram_tibble %>%
  arrange(desc(tf_idf)) %>%
  mutate(trigram = factor(trigram, levels = rev(unique(trigram)))) %>% 
  group_by(Box) %>% 
  top_n(10, tf_idf) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  ggplot(aes(trigram, tf_idf, fill = Box)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "tf-idf") +
  facet_wrap(~Box, ncol = 2, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip()
```

I have discovered (I think) that the 'top_n' function returns the trigrams which have the top ranking, and that it automatically uses the last variable in the tibble(in my case this is tf_idf, and I've chosen n-10).  However, when running this for bigrams I am only able to produce charts that seem to have several hundred (thousand??) bigrams along the y axis.

[image: tf-idf grouped by variable]

In the picture you can see that the negative variable seems fine (I've redacted it for data protection), but the other two are not!

I took this code from the tidy text mining book originally.

EDIT - ADDING A SAMPLE OF THE DATA

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLyos.png)

My best guess now is that the 'top_n' tf_idf scores happen to have many that are exactly the same.  In which case I'm now not sure this is a useful calculation and I'm wondering why it happened to work so well in the tidy text book, but not for my data.

### EDIT 2

I cut down the Trigram_tibble to 50 observations and this is the output of dput(Trigram_tibble) (I've obscured the survey response text trigrams)

> a<-Trigram_tibble [1:50, 1:8]
> dput(a)
> structure(list(Respondent = c(1294L, 2693L, 42L, 463L, 463L,
> 1481L, 1706L, 1891L, 1917L, 2442L, 2693L, 3590L, 3590L, 3916L,
> 4454L, 4682L, 5996L, 6283L, 6283L, 6568L, 9101L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
> 4L, 4L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
> 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L
> ), Box = c("Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative",
> "Negative", "Bank", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative",
> "Bank", "Bank", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative",
> "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative",
> "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Bank", "Bank",
> "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive",
> "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative",
> "Negative", "Bank", "Bank", "Bank", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative",
> "Negative", "Negative"), trigram = c("xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx",
> "xxx xxx xxx", "xxx xxx xxx"), n = c(4L,
> 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
> 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
> 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
> 1L), total = c(1714L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 836L,
> 1714L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 836L, 836L, 2899L, 1714L, 2899L,
> 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L,
> 2899L, 2899L, 836L, 836L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L,
> 1714L, 1714L, 1714L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 836L,
> 836L, 836L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L, 2899L), tf = c(0.00233372228704784,
> 0.00103483959986202, 0.000689893066574681, 0.000689893066574681,
> 0.000689893066574681, 0.000689893066574681, 0.00239234449760766,
> 0.00116686114352392, 0.000689893066574681, 0.000689893066574681,
> 0.000689893066574681, 0.00239234449760766, 0.00239234449760766,
> 0.000689893066574681, 0.00116686114352392, 0.000689893066574681,
> 0.000689893066574681, 0.000689893066574681, 0.000689893066574681,
> 0.000689893066574681, 0.000689893066574681, 0.00034494653328734,
> 0.00034494653328734, 0.00034494653328734, 0.00034494653328734,
> 0.00034494653328734, 0.00034494653328734, 0.00119617224880383,
> 0.00119617224880383, 0.00034494653328734, 0.00034494653328734,
> 0.00034494653328734, 0.00034494653328734, 0.00034494653328734,
> 0.00058343057176196, 0.00058343057176196, 0.00058343057176196,
> 0.00034494653328734, 0.00034494653328734, 0.00034494653328734,
> 0.00034494653328734, 0.00034494653328734, 0.00119617224880383,
> 0.00119617224880383, 0.00119617224880383, 0.00034494653328734,
> 0.00034494653328734, 0.00034494653328734, 0.00034494653328734,
> 0.00034494653328734), idf = c(-2.07944154167984, 0.405465108108164,
> 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811,
> 0, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, -2.07944154167984, 1.09861228866811,
> 0.405465108108164, 1.09861228866811, -0.693147180559945, 1.09861228866811,
> 1.09861228866811, 0, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, -1.29928298413026,
> 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811,
> 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811,
> 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811,
> 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811,
> 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811,
> 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811,
> 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811,
> 1.09861228866811, 1.09861228866811), tf_idf = c(-0.00485283907043135,
> 0.000419591350232664, 0.000757925000805871, 0.000757925000805871,
> 0.000757925000805871, 0.000757925000805871, 0, 0.0012819279914447,
> 0.000757925000805871, -0.00143459230195228, 0.000757925000805871,
> 0.00097001222035446, 0.00262825906379931, -0.000478197433984095,
> 0.0012819279914447, 0.000757925000805871, 0, 0.000757925000805871,
> 0.000757925000805871, -0.000896366322269928, 0.000757925000805871,
> 0.000378962500402935, 0.000378962500402935, 0.000378962500402935,
> 0.000378962500402935, 0.000378962500402935, 0.000378962500402935,
> 0.00131412953189965, 0.00131412953189965, 0.000378962500402935,
> 0.000378962500402935, 0.000378962500402935, 0.000378962500402935,
> 0.000378962500402935, 0.000640963995722351, 0.000640963995722351,
> 0.000640963995722351, 0.000378962500402935, 0.000378962500402935,
> 0.000378962500402935, 0.000378962500402935, 0.000378962500402935,
> 0.00131412953189965, 0.00131412953189965, 0.00131412953189965,
> 0.000378962500402935, 0.000378962500402935, 0.000378962500402935,
> 0.000378962500402935, 0.000378962500402935)), row.names = c(NA,
> -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could include a small amount of sample data.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to add a sample however the characters wont fit.
Df= 8 columns
Respondent, Box, Trigram, n, total, tf, idf, tf_idf

Comment: Can you modify your data to remove any personal information then post the output of `dput(Trigram_tibble)`?

Comment: ok i've added it. had to add as a picture because the formatting didn't show properly in text.

Comment: i have edited to add the output of dput(Trigram_tibble), using only 50 observations as otherwise it was incredibly long